# Sollte "auf jeden Fall" nicht "auf jedem Fall" sein?

Tags: preposition

"Fall" ist maskulin und weil wir keine Bewegung haben, müsste "auf" den Dativ verlangen.  Erzwingt "auf" hier nicht den Dativ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich weiß nicht, wer dieses Bewegungs-Argument aufgebracht hat, aber es ist nutzlos:

> 1. Ich gehe auf **den** Berg.
> 2. Ich gehe auf **dem** Berg.

Beide Sätze sind korrekt, und in beiden gibt es eine Bewegung.

1. Ich bin noch im Tal und bewege mich in eine bestimmte Richtung (nämlich auf **den** Berg).
2. Ich bin bereits an einem bestimmten Ort (nämlich auf **dem** Berg) und bewege mich dort, ohne diesen Ort zu verlassen.

Das heißt:

- Bewegung in eine bestimmte **Richtung**: Akkusativ
- Bewegung an einem gleichbleibenden **Ort**: Dativ

---

### Aber:

Ein *Fall* ist weder eine Richtung noch ein Ort. Argumente, die Richtungen, Orte oder Bewegungen beinhalten, greifen hier völlig ins Leere. Das sind Argumente, die bei **lokalen** Präpositionen helfen. Das ist hier aber nicht der Fall.

Es gibt nämlich auch noch **temporale, kausale** und **modale** Präpositionen, und das Wort *»auf«* kann in allen vier Geschmacksrichtungen vorkommen. (Es gibt auch noch andere Arten von Präpositionen, die aber für *»auf«* nicht in Frage kommen).

Das sind die Regeln für die Präposition **auf**:

- **lokal, Richtung: Akkusativ**

  > Ich gehe auf **den** Berg.
- **lokal, Ort: Dativ**

  > Ich gehe auf **dem** Berg.
- **temporal: Dativ**

  > Auf **dem** Fest waren viele Leute.
- **modal: Akkusativ**

  > Das muss auf **den** Millimeter genau passen.
- **kausal: Akkusativ**

  > Ich bin hier auf **(den)** Wunsch meines Chefs.

Comment: Ist "auf" in "auf jeden Fall" eine modale Präposition?  Ich schaue diese Regeln hier an: https://easy-deutsch.de/en/prepositions/#tab-con-4

Comment: Die Regeln erscheinen zweifelhaft. So unterscheiden etwa Zifonun et al.,  IDS-Grammatik, Bd. 3, S. 2122 f. bereits bei der temporalen Verwendung "_auf_ + Akkusativ (prospektiv)" von "_auf_ + Dativ (gleichzeitig 'quasilokal')". Ein Beispiel für die Akkusativrektion wäre etwa _auf zwei Jahre nach Amerika fahren, sich auf 15 Uhr verabreden_. So leicht lässt sich das Ganze mithin m.E. nicht in Regeln pressen. Vgl. auch im modalen Bereich: _jmdn. auf diese Weise kontaktieren_ vs. _jmdn. auf diesem Weg kontaktieren_. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Die Prämisse "weil wir keine Bewegung haben, muss 'auf' Dativ sein" ist nicht richtig. Wenn die Präposition weder lokal noch direktiv gebraucht ist, fällt sie aus diesem Paradigma heraus. Vgl. http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=1449 (Nicht-lokale Präpositionen: Temporaler und instrumentaler Gebrauch):

> Eine Übertragung von lokalen auf andere Bereiche ist nicht ohne Weiteres möglich. Zwar werden die lokalen Präpositionen weitgehend für andere, etwa temporale oder kausale Spezifikationen genutzt, das Konzept der Regionenkonstitution ist hier aber nicht sinnvoll anwendbar [...] So macht es sicherlich keinen Sinn, etwa bei *am Montag* von einer temporalen AN-Region zu sprechen in Analogie zu *am Tisch*. Auch fallen die temporalen Lesarten so unterschiedlicher Präpositionen wie *an*, *in*, *um* weitgehend zusammen: Es wird jeweils ein Betrachtzeitintervall spezifiziert, innerhalb dessen die Ereigniszeit liegen muss.

"An" steht in diesen Fällen häufiger mit dem Akkusativ. Vgl. Duden-Grammatik, 8. Aufl., Rn. 913:

> Bei nicht lokaler und nicht temporaler Verwendung, d. h. bei Abwesenheit einer
>   Raum/Zeit-Vorstellung, regieren *an*, *in*, *neben*, *unter*, *vor* und *zwischen* den Dativ, *auf* regiert oft den Akkusativ.

(Als Beispiel werden eben "auf jeden Fall" und "auf jede Weise" angegeben.)